# How to use sed to extract a field from a delimited file

Tags: text, awk, sed, centos

Am using centos 7 linux

I do have a text file which a lot of lines in same format which is email,password

example:

test@test.com,test

i would like to use sed to only save test@test.com and remove `,test`which means it's will remove from all lines starting from ','.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it's return with awk: cmd. line:1: {print
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ unexpected newline or end of string

Comment: check your code for errors/typos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Setop's answer is good - in general, using `cut` or `awk` is an usual practice while dealing with delimited files.

We can use `sed` as well, as per your question:

```
sed -i 's/,.*//' file # changes the file in-place
```

or, using two steps:

```
sed 's/,.*//' file > file.modified && mv file.modified file
```

- `s/,.*//` replaces `,` and all characters after it with nothing

This can get trickier if you have multiple fields and want a small subset from it.

Answer (score 3):

```
cut -d, -f1 yourfile
```

or

```
awk -F, '{print $1}'
```